# Bash script - stdout file descriptor?

Tags: bash, stdout

I have the following in my script:

```
OUTFILE=./output.log
echo "foo" >> ${OUTFILE}
```

It works just fine when `OUTFILE` is an actual file path. However, sometimes I'd like to see the output on stdout by modifying `OUTFILE` but it doesn't work. I tried with `1` and `&1`, both quoted and unquoted, as well as leaving it empty.
It just keeps telling me this:

```
./foo.sh: line 2: ${OUTFILE}: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: What do you mean tried `1` and `&1` ? Are you trying to write to the file and stdout or just stdout? If the former use tee.

Comment: @Simon Stop giving bad suggestions, your first comment will also give a syntax error and doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `/dev/stdout` as your filename for this. (See the [Portability of “> /dev/stdout”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36403/67134).)

You can't use `&1` in the variable because of parsing order issues. The redirection tokens are searched for *before* variable expansion is performed. So when you use:

```
$ o='&1'
$ echo >$o
```

the shell scans for redirection operators and sees the `>` redirection operator and not the `>&` operator. (And there isn't a `>>&` operator to begin with anyway so your appending example wouldn't work regardless. Though newer versions of bash do have an `&>>` operator for `>> file 2>&1` use.)

Answer (score 6):

Im guessing you want to do one of these

#### Print to file

```
OUTFILE=./output.log
echo "foo" >> "${OUTFILE}"
```

#### Print to stdout

```
OUTFILE=/dev/stdout
echo "foo" >> "${OUTFILE}"
```

or just

```
echo "foo"
```

#### Print to file and stdout

```
OUTFILE=./output.log
echo "foo" | tee  "${OUTFILE}"
```